# Is there a word for beautiful/happy/pleasant dream?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one-word to represent a pleasant dream - a dream that leaves lingering happiness. Exactly unlike a nightmare. So I am basically looking for an antonym of nightmare

Comment: *Dream* is both the antonym and hypernym for nightmare.

Comment: This is a dupe of [an earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/193878/55623); the short answer given there is that there is no single word, but the idiom "***sweet dreams***" comes close.