# What is the word for the feeling of loss that is experienced when you wake from a dream?

Tags: single-word-requests

I seem to remember that there's a word for the feeling you get when you are having a dream that's vivid and happy, then you wake up and that's gone, it's a sadness and it's not necessarily fleeting. It may be one of those non-English words that has no English equivalent. Does anyone know?

Comment: just outside the ball-park: ephemera/l/ity; evanescent

Comment: You need to provide more focus. Are you thinking of something that's only applicable to dreams? What words have you already considered and rejected, and why?

Comment: Well of course your bubble has burst, but that doesn't really capture the sense of loss.

Comment: Are you thinking about something along the lines of "bereft"?

Comment: I think there might not be a single word in english. I might be searching for a foreign word. Heres an example. My friend had a dream where he met a girl, fell in love, was married and living a blissful fulfilling life. Then his alarm went off. He woke up and was sad for a day because it was so real that his sense of grief and loss was real. Ive had things like that too. I know a lot of people that have. I am pretty sure there is a single word for this specific feeling of loss from waking from a dream. It may be a French word. I think its a specific word just for this too.

Comment: There is a feeling of uncanniness is situations like this. Would it be too much to ask for you to capitalize the word English? Also, "it's" with an apostrophe and not "its" in your paragraph. These usages would signal a minimum respect for the writing here.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535263/single-word-for-when-youve-just-met-someone-but-you-experience-a-kind-of-sad-no/536482#536482

Comment: correction to my post: in situations like this

Comment: If the feeling of loss/depression is experienced after waking up from a nightmare, there is a rare word for it: [malneirophrenia](https://wordinfo.info/unit/1476). The good feeling after a pleasant dream is _euneirophrenia_ [*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193932/64985). It appears that there isn't a word coined for the bad feeling after a happy dream. It could be "anti-euneirophrenia".

Answer (score 1):

The closest word I can think of for such a situation is **wistfulness.**

> a feeling of sadness because you are thinking about something that is **impossible or in the past**

*He admits a certain wistfulness for his days as governor.*

*A return to the dream of childhood innocence is mere wistfulness.*

[Cambridge]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional possibilities:

**Melancholia**

> - suggestive or expressive of sadness or depression of mind or spirit
> - causing or tending to cause sadness or depression of mind or spirit
> - depressed in spirits : dejected, sad pensive

*[Merriam Webster]*

**Pensive**

> - musingly or dreamily thoughtful
> - suggestive of sad thoughtfulness

*[Merriam Webster]*

Answer (score 0):

A dream is an illusion - when you wake, you become disillusioned.

> **disillusionment** noun [ U or S ] UK  /ˌdɪs.ɪˈluː.ʒən.mənt/ US  /ˌdɪs.ɪˈluː.ʒən.mənt/ (also **disillusion**)   a feeling of being
> disappointed and unhappy because of discovering the truth about
> something or someone that you liked or respected:
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disillusionment

Answer (score -1):

A word that seems to me to be closely related to what you seek is **nostalgia**: from [Merriam–Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgia),

> a wistful or excessively sentimental yearning for return to or of some past period or irrecoverable condition.

It applies more directly to happy memories than to good dreams, but since it is impossible to return to either I think it may fit well.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted.