# Single word for when you've just met someone but you experience a kind of sad nostalgia after they leave

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a Single word for when you just met someone but you get kind-of a sad nostalgia after they left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word might be *[desiderium](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desiderium)*, defined as *an ardent desire or longing, especially a feeling of loss or grief for something lost*.

Within the [classification of emotions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_classification), I think it is either *[saudade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade)* or *[grief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grief)*.

Answer (score 3):

newantman has already given the best possible words but I'll still write my answer.

That feeling could be described as **wistfulness**.

**Wistfulness** means full of melancholy longing or wishful yearning.

"She seemed wistful for the old days when I'd hung around her all the time".

Comment: I think this is a great one!

Answer (score 2):

**Moved**

: [Cambridge]
having strong feelings of sadness or sympathy, because of something someone has said or done:

"I was really **moved** by Rachel's visit. Knowing she would leave to travel across countey, never to be seen again, I nearly proposed on the spot."

*Touched* is listed as a relevant synonym.

Answer (score 1):

How about the Yiddish, **SCHMALTZ** ? (adj. schmaltzy) 'excessively sentimental'. By way of chicken/goose fat. Might taste OK but not very good for your heart. After all if you're feeling sad after seeing your old friend leave, your current friend would be justified calling you a schmaltz. In my humble opinion.